# Tumblr-alike grid with flexbox, tallest element messes margins on all elements under it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a tumblr alike grid with panels all over it, but apparently when the panel is taller than the adjactent ones, it'll mess with top margins of panels below.

Here's a visualisation:
[image]

I've looked all around the web and found some libraries that solve this issue, but I would have to have to remake this whole thing before trying to solve it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may need to install masonry on your theme, it should do the trick. here's a tutorial which worked fine for me http://manatopia.tumblr.com/post/21987192834/teach-me-how-06-masonry i hope this helps!